# How to handle unused variable in javascript function eslint errors?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have the following JavaScript functions which are linked to a HTML file, as they are called by a recordHistory() button in the HTML file. The JavaScript work well functionally, but in validation using eslint shows me these errors:
'alerts' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars) (this error for alert.js file)

```
// JavaScript Document
function validateFirstName() { //test input for 2-15 allowed characters
    var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var rel = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-]{2,15}$/;
    
    if (rel.test(fName)) { //if input is valid, update page to show successful entry}
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>valid</strong>"
        return true;
}
    else { //if input is invalid, update page to prompt for new input
            document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").style.color = "Red";
            document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>Enter 2&15</strong>"
            return false;
    }   
}

function validateLastName() { //test input for 2-25 allowed characters
    var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    var re2 = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-']{2,25}$/;
    
    if (re2.test(lName)) { //if input is valid, update page to show successful entry}
        document.getElementById("lastNamePrompt").style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById("lastNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>valid</strong>"
        return true;
}
    else { //if input is invalid, update page to prompt for new input
            document.getElementById("lastNamePrompt").style.color = "Red";
            document.getElementById("lastNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>Enter 2&25</strong>"
            return false;
    }   
}

function recordHistory(){//function to validate input text fields on client side, via record button
var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
if( fName ==='' || lName ===''){
alert("Please fill all text fields...!!!!!!");
return false;
}else{
return true;
}   
}
```

The error occurs at these lines:-

1. function validateFirstName() { //test input for 2-15 allowed characters
2. function validateLastName() { //test input for 2-25 allowed characters
3. function recordHistory(){//function to validate input text fields on client side, via record button

In the HTML file, the JavaScript functions are called by this function recordHistory():-

```
<tr>
        <td class="Button" id="Button" colspan="3"><span class="buttonBG" onclick="recordHistory();">Record</span></td>              
</tr>
```

I referenced an example from this link [Disallow Unused Variables (no-unused-vars)][1] to help me solve the problem, but I couldn't get it to work

[1]: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars: -

```
// foo is considered used here
myFunc(function foo() {
    // ...
}.bind(this));

(function(foo) {
    return foo;
})();
```

This was what I tried for the FirstName JavaScript function, for example, but it didn't work: -

```
myFunc(function validateFirstName() { //test input for 2-15 allowed characters
    var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var rel = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-]{2,15}$/;
}.bind(this));
(function(validateFirstName) {if (rel.test(fName)) { //if input is valid, update page to show successful entry}
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>valid</strong>"
        return true;
}
    else { //if input is invalid, update page to prompt for new input
            document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").style.color = "Red";
            document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>Enter 2&15</strong>"
            return false;
    }   
})();
```

Comment: You'd need to tell eslint that these are declared globally. Or you should just use proper event listener, attached from JS, instead of putting event handler attributes in the html.

Comment: @Bergi: thanks for your help. I added /* exported global_var */  but the errors still persists. Unfortunately, I am required to put an event handler attribute in the html for this task.